# What is the entity ID for private messages?

Tags: 7, entities, privatemsg

I want to access some private messages using `entity_load()` but I don't know what the entity ID is to call them by.  I have the message ID (mid) but that doesn't appear to work.

I'm attempting to load an individual message like this:

```
      $message_entity = entity_load('privatemsg_message', array($row['mid']));
```

And this is how Private Message declares `hook_entity_property_info()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info().
 */
function privatemsg_entity_property_info() {
  $info = array();
  // Add meta-data about the basic node properties.
  $properties = &$info['privatemsg_message']['properties'];
  $properties = array(
    'mid' => array(
      'type'  => 'integer',
      'label' => t('Private message ID'),
      'description' => t('Private message ID'),
    ),
    'thread_id' => array(
      'type'  => 'integer',
      'label' => t('Private message thread ID'),
      'description' => t('Private message thread ID'),
      'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
    ),
    'author' => array(
      'type'  => 'user',
      'label' => t('Private message author'),
      'description' => t('Private message author'),
      'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
    ),
    'subject' => array(
      'type'  => 'text',
      'label' => t('Private message subject'),
      'description' => t('Private message subject'),
      'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
    ),
    'body' => array(
      'type'  => 'text',
      'label' => t('Private message body'),
      'description' => t('Private message body'),
      'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
    ),
    'timestamp' => array(
      'type' => 'date',
      'label' => t('Private message sent date'),
      'description' => t('Private message sent date'),
    ),
  );
  return $info;
}
```

How do I get the entity ID for private messages?  Is that different than the message ID (mid) or thread ID (thread_id)?

Comment: If I recall correctly, message id is **mid**.

Comment: try `$message_entity = entity_load('privatemsg_message', array('mid'));`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out **mid** is correct, but for whatever reason `$row['mid']` was returning a string, not an int.  Type-casting the string as an int solved the problem.